# Inverse image of rationals under tangent function is free abelian?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-equations

It is easy to see that the set $\{x:\tan x\in \Bbb Q \,\, or\,\, \pm\infty\}$ forms a group under addition.
It is a free abelian group?

Comment: Nice question, but what does it have to do with Grobner bases?

Comment: The "Grobner" is error just taken to upload the problem.Sorry.

Comment: Your group $M$ a torsion-free countable abelian group, hence it's free abelian iff all its subgroups of finite rank are finitely generated; here this means that for every finite-dimensional $\mathbf{Q}$-linear subspace $V$ of $\mathbf{R}$, the subgroup $M\cap V$ is finitely generated. Nice question, maybe should be posted on mathoverflow.

Comment: I informed that it was proved the group is free abelian.